# using mongoimport doesnt save data properly

Tags: json, mongodb

So instead of using mongo shell directly i decided it was easier to create a json file and then just import it to monngodb, but something strange happens in the process. Heres my code:

mongoimport --db test_poke --collection testing --type json --file pokeapi.json --jsonArray

2017-09-24T23:45:44.017-0400    connected to: localhost
2017-09-24T23:45:44.624-0400    imported 4 documents

```
> show dbs
admin       0.000GB
anime       0.000GB
api         0.000GB
exampleDb   0.000GB
local       0.000GB
myDB        0.000GB
pokedex     0.000GB
superheros  0.000GB
test_poke   0.000GB
users       0.000GB
yUser       0.000GB
> use test_poke
switched to db test_poke
> db.test_poke.find()
> db.test_poke.find({})
```

// json data

```
  {
    "name": "pikachu",
    "size": "small",
    "element_type": "electric"
  },
  {
    "name": "squirtle",
    "size": "small",
    "element_type": "water"

  },
  {
    "name": "charmander",
    "size": "small",
    "element_type": "fire"
  },
  {
    "name": "bulbasoor",
    "size": "small",
    "element_type": "earth"
  }
```

no data is found i guess because nothing is returned but using anything else to CRUD works and shows results. Also I read the docs and made sure to follow their instructions but no go. Can anyone help with this? Using version 3.4.7 of mongodb.

Comment: `db.testing.find()` ?

Comment: i tried that, didnt show as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your collection is called `testing` and is in the `test_poke` database.  As the comment suggests your query is wrong, and should be

```
db.testing.find()
```

Comment: i switched to testing as well and it didnt work. meant to add that before i left for work